Can't see size/usage information for system folders
I'm getting close to filling my ~600GB root directory. I know that I can expand it - but in the first instance I'd like to know what's taking up the space.
sudo du and sudo ncdu show:
28G     home
18G     var
4.1G    swap.img
3.6G    usr
252M    boot
39M     lost+found
5.8M    etc
4.6M    run
76K     tmp
56K     root
24K     snap
16K     opt
4.0K    srv
4.0K    mnt
4.0K    media
0       sys
0       sbin
0       proc
0       libx32
0       lib64
0       lib32
0       lib
0       dev
0       bin

sudo df shows:
Filesystem                              Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                                   2.0G  4.9M  2.0G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv       628G  463G  139G  77% /
tmpfs                                   9.8G     0  9.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                   5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
/dev/sda2                               2.0G  254M  1.6G  14% /boot
tmpfs                                   2.0G  4.0K  2.0G   1% /run/user/1000

I've run things like autoclean and autoremove - no change.
Any ideas? Thanks!

From your question. /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv       628G  463G  139G  77% / You must have installed something a lot of something.

Thanks - and so how do I see what's in there? When I navigate to /dev/mapper, it shows as 0 storage used - and ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv doesn't seem to be a directory.
